# Inferring U,V for a point in a Triangle from Vertex U,V's

Tags: python, geometry, raytracing, cgkit

I am writing a very simple ray-tracer in python using [CGKit](https://github.com/justinfx/cgkit) and [RTree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/). After intersecting the ray with the triangle, I would like to infer the U,V of the intersection point from the U,V's of the vertex. What is the appropriate way for doing this ?

Currently I am using a weighted average of the distance from opposite edge as shown below. Apart from the CGKit related stuff, I have 3 vertices v1,v2,v3 and 3 UV's vt1,vt2,vt3. hit_p is the xyz point on the triangle returned by CGKit intersection.

```
def extract_hit_vt(tri_geom, tri_vt,hit_p, oa_face):

    hit_face = tri_geom.faces[oa_face]

    vt1 = np.array(vec3(tri_vt[oa_face * 3]))
    vt2 = np.array(vec3(tri_vt[oa_face * 3 + 1]))
    vt3 = np.array(vec3(tri_vt[oa_face * 3 + 2]))

    v1 = tri_geom.verts[hit_face[0]]
    v2 = tri_geom.verts[hit_face[1]]
    v3 = tri_geom.verts[hit_face[2]]

    d1 = ptlined(v2, v3, hit_p)
    d2 = ptlined(v3, v1, hit_p)
    d3 = ptlined(v1, v2, hit_p)

    hit_vt = (d1*vt1+d2*vt2+d3*vt3)/(d1+d2+d3)

    return hit_vt
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main thing to decide is how exactly you want to interpolate UV inside of triangles. Since you said you have only three points, you unlikely may do better than a simple linear interpolation.

In this case you need barycenric coordinates of the point inside of the triangle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system

In short, every point inside of triangle can be represented as weighted sum of its vertices, where every weight is between 0 and 1. The weights can be found by solving 2x2 system of linear equations.

When you have these weights, you can use them to get weighted sum of UV coordinates.

Comment: Thanks that was easier than I expected. http://cgkit.sourceforge.net/doc2/trimeshgeom.html already returns U,V for the intersection point. I will use (1-u-v), u, v as the weights.

Answer (score 4):

This is the code taken from LuxRays (http://src.luxrender.net/luxrays). To obtain the barycentric coordinates:

```
static bool GetBaryCoords(const Point &p0, const Point &p1, const Point &p2,
        const Point &hitPoint, float *b1, float *b2) {
    const Vector u = p1 - p0;
    const Vector v = p2 - p0;
    const Vector w = hitPoint - p0;

    const Vector vCrossW = Cross(v, w);
    const Vector vCrossU = Cross(v, u);

    if (Dot(vCrossW, vCrossU) < 0.f)
        return false;

    const Vector uCrossW = Cross(u, w);
    const Vector uCrossV = Cross(u, v);

    if (Dot(uCrossW, uCrossV) < 0.f)
        return false;

    const float denom = uCrossV.Length();
    const float r = vCrossW.Length() / denom;
    const float t = uCrossW.Length() / denom;

    *b1 = r;
    *b2 = t;

    return ((r <= 1.f) && (t <= 1.f) && (r + t <= 1.f));
}
```

p0, p1, p2 are the triangle vertex, hitPoint is the ray/triangle intersection point and barycentric coordinates are returned in b1, b2.
Once you have b1, b2 you can obtain the interpolated (u, v) values with:

```
const float b0 = 1.f - b1 - b2;
const u = b0 * u_v0 + b1 * u_v1 + b2 * u_v2;
const v = b0 * v_v0 + b1 * v_v1 + b2 * v_v2;
```

Where u_v0, v_v0, etc, are the (u, v) coordinates of triangle vertex.